# Copy constructor for class that has member without default constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, deep-copy, default-constructor

I have a class:

```
class Geometry{
    std::vector<Subset *> subsets;
    int verticesCount;
    ...
};
```

I want to add a copy constructor, so I can make a **deep copy** of that object (with own `subsets`, **NOT** only own **pointers** to same `subsets`).

I have tried this:

```
 Geometry & Geometry::operator=(const Geometry &other){
      verticesCount = other.verticesCount;
      Subset * subset = 0;
      for(unsigned int i=0; i<other.subsets.size(); i++){
           subset = new Subset();
           subsets.push_back(subset);
      }
      ...
      return *this;
 }
```

The problem is `Subset` has **none** default constructor, so I get error at `subset = new Subset()`.

I also have more members that don't have default constructors.

**How to solve that problem?**

I would prefer **NOT to add default constructors**  for all that members (`Subset` etc.) The best solution would be *NOT* to change member classes at all (`Subset` etc.), but I can add something to them, if it's necessary.

They don't have default constructors for **reasons**, e.g. security (I don't want to let somebody create a `Model3D` class without giving filename (so the vertex buffers can be created and I can assume that all `Model3D` objects has not-empty filename associated).

---

edit:

Because of comment. `Subset` is an example of member class without default constructor.

In that case it's my own class:

```
class Subset{
    ...
    public:
        Subset(bool useLineTopology, int vertexIndexStart, int vertexIndexAmmount = -1);
        ...
};
```

But I also have many others members without default constructor, like DirectX's `ID3D11Buffer * constantBuffer`.

Comment: So what constructors DOES `Subset` actually have? What is `Subset` anyway?

Comment: Does Subset have a copy constructor?
could you do something like:
   subsets.push_back(new Subset(other.subsets[i]));
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Subset()` class has a copy constructor then you can do as follows:

```
std::vector<Subset *>::const_iterator it ; // use iterators
for ( it = other.subsets.begin() ; it != other.subsets.end() ; ++it )
    subset.push_back( new Subset( *it )) ; // add a copy of original subset.
```

If your `Subset()` does not have copy constructor then you CANNOT copy.

Also, you need to remember to have `~GeometryStructure()` in order to delete all `Subset()` objects from the `subset std::vector`

Comment: So the solution would be to add copy constructors to the member classes that don't have default constructors?

Comment: Yes. Only this way you can have 'deep copy' as you need. The `GeometryStructure()`, and all its members, and members all its members have to have it.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a deep copy, so your loop should look like

```
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<other.subsets.size(); i++){
       subsets.push_back(new Subset(other.subsets[i]));
  }
```

that is, you need a *copy constructor* for the elements. Even if `Subset` had a default constructor, you wouldn't be copying anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
class Geometry{
    std::vector<Subset> subsets;
    int verticesCount;
    ...
};
```

if you implement copy and/or move semantics to your Subset class, you do not need to create constructors because the compiler will take charge of invoking Subset copy constructors et al. Other favorable point is that you do not need to worry about destructing subsets when your Geometry instances are being destructed.

Comment: I guess adding copy constructors to the member classes will require less reorganization in code. Anyway, voted up, because it's an alternative solution. :)

Comment: @oopscene Note that in this case, apart from the needed code re-organization, the absence of a default constructor for `Subset` would limit the use of the vector, e.g. you wouldn't be able to construct it with a given size or [`resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) it (check type requirements).