# How to add elements to vector<MyType> when MyType has no default constructor and no copy constructor?

Tags: c++, vector

In short, I'd like to add elements to a vector of class elements when that class does not define a copy constructor and does not have a default constructor. Here's a minimal example (thanks juanchopanza for fixing my example):

```
class MyType {
 public:
  MyType(int height, int width);
  MyType() = delete;
}

#include <vector>
int some_function() {
  // Define the vector.
  std::vector<MyType> array;
  // Define an element.
  MyType element(1,2);
  // Now, how do I add an element to the vector?
  //array.resize(1); // NO DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR SO THIS WON'T WORK.
  //array.push_back(element); // NO COPY CONSTRUCTOR SO THIS WON'T WORK.
}
```

My best guess is that I can't use vectors with a class unless it has a copy constructor or a default constructor. Looking for validation or enlightenment.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952912/vectorpush-back-myclass-not-work-for-non-default-constructor), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338620/copy-constructor-for-class-that-has-member-without-default-constructor-in-c), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512049/vector-push-back-uses-default-constructor-not-copy-constructor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310638/c-vectorpush-back-using-default-copy-constructor), but none of them address my question.

Comment: Have you accidentally made `MyType` copy constructable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the type is move-constructable, you can construct it in-place with `emplace_back`:

```
array.emplace_back(1,2);
```

But note that your example *does* have a copy constructor, so this would also work, contrary to your claims:

```
MyType element(1,2);
array.push_back(element);
```

Here's a shortened, working version of your example:

```
struct MyType 
{
  MyType(int height, int width) {}
  MyType() = delete;
};

#include <vector>

int main() 
{
  std::vector<MyType> array;
  array.emplace_back(1,2);
}
```

Comment: right on! thank you. Will accept as soon as stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: so, until c++11, this wasn't possible?!

Comment: @Ammar Actually, your example *does* have a copy constructor. Without one, my example doesn't work.